How to find pmi and phrase-count for everygrams?
Using NLTK's library I can find metrics about bi and trigrams . Now I want to find all the possible phrases and find their  occurence count and PMI score as I did with the bi-grams and trigrams like this :
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *


trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
finder2 = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(one_string1.split())
# only trigrams that appear  10+ time
finder2.apply_freq_filter(10)

# finding trigram's pmi
trigram_pmi = [i for i in finder2.score_ngrams(trigram_measures.pmi)] # [(( phrase1, phrase2 ), pmi) ]
#finding trigram's count 
trigram_freq1 = finder2.ngram_fd.items()

Essentially , what I want is to find the most likely and common phrases in my text regardless of size ,i.e. the phrase " on the other" should have a lower pmi than "on the other hand" while the phrase "good bye" should rank higher than "said good bye" . I am looking to implemement something like NLTK's everygram() feature but also get the metrics . There seems to be no easy way to do it and I imagine I'll have to use a for loop and calculate it manually . I was thinking of something like:
bi_pmi_list =[]
tri_pmi_list =[]
quad_pmi_list =[
bigram_measures  = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
quadgram_measures= nltk.collocations.QuadgramAssocMeasures()
for phrase in everygram_phrases_list:
    if len(phrase) == 2:
         bi_pmi = finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.pmi)

         bi_pmi_list.append(bi_pmi)
# same thing for tri and quad and similar idea then for computing the counts

But prefer a cleaner way and also I am limited beyond 4 word phrases as well .
Excuse me if some parts don't make sense - I am new to coding !
